# Change label's value to the current nonsubmitted value of username input box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a login page, where users only have 1 input box = for their username. Once they enter their username, this form hides itself and the next form for password shows.

On the top left corner of the second form, there is a left arrow icon (that goes back to the first form - the username form).

On the right of the left arrow icon, I've tried putting the value of what they entered in the first input box. Their username. But I am unsuccessful. It seems that I cannot do that, since all I end up doing is setting the text next to the left arrow icon to a predefined value. I can't get the label to update to the username they've entered on the previous form.

The website consists of HTML,CSS,Javascript with only 1 PHP POST request.

What I've tried so far:

```
$("#test").text('id$=testx');
```

I'm really clueless when it comes to scripts. After this code, the value of label shows `id$=testx`

I need it to show the input value of input box with `id="testx"`.

As you can also see the label id is "test"

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var username_val = document.getElementById('testx').value;
$("#test").text(username_val);
```

You just had the wrong syntax.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It's changing it now, but not from the first try. When I put that and click enter, it goes to the second form. The second form's label is empty again, but when I go back and press enter again - then it appears. Is it possible to get the value of the label replaced from the first try?

Comment: You will need to provide more of the code so that we can understand what is happening better.